# Create a list with lists of subsets of a given size of set

Tags: python, list, dictionary, subset, combinations

I need to write a code that gives back the subsets of a given size of a set in a list.
 So first let's say I want subsets of size 3 from a set (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

And I want to write out the subsets in a list:

[[0,1,2],[0,2,3],[0,3,4]....]

And then I would like to go with recursion in it and compare all the elements except the first with my dictionary(graph), to check there are in my  value, which is a list. The key of dictionary is the first element in my subset.

Like for example:

in [0,1,2]:

is 1 and 2 in graph[0]?

the dictionary graph is sth like: {0:[1,2,3,6,7], 1:[0,2,4,6,7]....}

And if I am done and everything is there, I want to check the next subset.

So my problem how can i put this in a list? I know I have a problem with k too but not sure how to change it.

```
def indep(graph,a,b):
    l=list( itertools.combinations(range(a), b))
    for k in l:
        k=list(k)
        while j<=len(k):
           for j in range(len(k)): 
              if k[j]  in graph[k[j]]:
                 j+=1
              else:
                return "no"
```

Comment: Please check if that is something you needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you expected result

from itertools import combinations

```
original_set = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
final_set = [list(pair) for pair in combinations(l, 3)]

Out[6]: 
[[0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 3],
 [0, 1, 4],
 [0, 1, 5],
 [0, 1, 6],
 [0, 1, 7],
 [0, 1, 8],
 [0, 2, 3],
 [0, 2, 4],
 [0, 2, 5],
 [0, 2, 6],
 [0, 2, 7],
 [0, 2, 8],
 [0, 3, 4],
 [0, 3, 5],
 [0, 3, 6],
 [0, 3, 7],
 [0, 3, 8],
 [0, 4, 5],
 [0, 4, 6],
 [0, 4, 7],
 [0, 4, 8],
 [0, 5, 6],
 [0, 5, 7],
 [0, 5, 8],
 [0, 6, 7],
 [0, 6, 8],
 [0, 7, 8],
 [1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 4],
 [1, 2, 5],
 [1, 2, 6],
 [1, 2, 7],
 [1, 2, 8],
 [1, 3, 4],
 [1, 3, 5],
 [1, 3, 6],
 [1, 3, 7],
 [1, 3, 8],
 [1, 4, 5],
 [1, 4, 6],
 [1, 4, 7],
 [1, 4, 8],
 [1, 5, 6],
 [1, 5, 7],
 [1, 5, 8],
 [1, 6, 7],
 [1, 6, 8],
 [1, 7, 8],
 [2, 3, 4],
 [2, 3, 5],
 [2, 3, 6],
 [2, 3, 7],
 [2, 3, 8],
 [2, 4, 5],
 [2, 4, 6],
 [2, 4, 7],
 [2, 4, 8],
 [2, 5, 6],
 [2, 5, 7],
 [2, 5, 8],
 [2, 6, 7],
 [2, 6, 8],
 [2, 7, 8],
 [3, 4, 5],
 [3, 4, 6],
 [3, 4, 7],
 [3, 4, 8],
 [3, 5, 6],
 [3, 5, 7],
 [3, 5, 8],
 [3, 6, 7],
 [3, 6, 8],
 [3, 7, 8],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [4, 5, 7],
 [4, 5, 8],
 [4, 6, 7],
 [4, 6, 8],
 [4, 7, 8],
 [5, 6, 7],
 [5, 6, 8],
 [5, 7, 8],
 [6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

# all sets here.
sets = [list(x) for x in itertools.permutations(a, 3) if x[1]==x[2]-1]

#here are all the sets
#[[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 4], [0, 4, 5], [0, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 5], [1, 5, 6], [2, 0, 1], [2, 3, 4],
#[2, 4, 5], [2, 5, 6], [3, 0, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [3, 5, 6], [4, 0, 1], [4, 1, 2], [4, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [5, 0, 1], 
#[5, 1, 2], [5, 2, 3], [5, 3, 4], [6, 0, 1], [6, 1, 2], [6, 2, 3], [6, 3, 4], [6, 4, 5]]

d = dict()
#make your thingy
for i in sets:
    try:
        d[i[0]] = d[i[0]]+i[1:]
    except:
        d[i[0]] = i[1:]

    d[i[0]] = list(set(d[i[0]]))

#output D

{0: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 1: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 2: [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 3: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6],
 4: [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6],
 5: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 6: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

is this what you wanted? :D

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering but its not what i wanted. First I want to print out all subsets in a list:   [[0,1,2], [0,2,3],[0,3,5].....and so on]

Comment: sets has all the subsets in a list. What was the second thing?

Comment: if i have the list [[0,1,2],[,1,2,3],[,0,1,4],,,,,,] how should i go on every element and compare it with my values of  dictionary?

Comment: What do you mean by compare? Every element of your given list of lists is a list and the values in your dictionaries will be list. What do you mean by comparing list?